# How to enable self signed certificates in Windows 10?

Tags: certificates

I want to use a Yubikey 4 with Windows 10 Pro for Bitlocker and login with my TPM.

Unfortunately, I found out I need to enable self signed certificates and all the guides on the Internet I found were either outdated or simply didn't work.

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 1):

> Better late than never:

Go to regeditor to the path: Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\FVE

- Add *SelfSignedCertificates* as DWORD entry (if non exists).
- Update the value to 1.

This will allow you to use SelfSignedCertificates with BitLocker.

---

Your certificate needs to meet the following requirements:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd875548(v=ws.10)

Or you can use a cert generated from the EFS wizzard and follow the following instructions:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-7/dd875530(v=ws.10)#sharing-an-efs-certificate-with-bitlocker